# redirection from non-www to www and http to https in IIS

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-8

I am trying to redirect from non-www site to www and also from http to https.

Http to https works well, but non-www to www shows a page not found error.

This is my configuration:

```
         <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="non-www to www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="http to https" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

What is going on? I have tried several variants for non-www to www, all from sites found in google, but non worked.

Jaime

Comment: Use FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Note that you cannot use Rewrite as action most of the time.

Comment: Thanks!!! I haven't realized that the action type was "Rewrite". By changing to "Redirect" it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment with more explanation.

The action should be set to `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`, because you do want search engines to show www links, and then your site must issue 301 redirection to their bots.

> Even if you sometimes want `Rewrite`, the `url` must be a relative path to the same site. If rewriting to another site (like the one you used above), then ARR is required with proxy mode. Otherwise, IIS naturally returns 404 errors.
>
> However, rewriting does not change URLs in browser address bar, so it also has no effect on search engine bots.

[Reference](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59)